Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\omega)}:\mathbb{Q}$
Given the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}$ where $\alpha=\sqrt[5]{3}$ I was instructed to construct the normal closure of the extension, which I found to be $\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\omega)}$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$.
Now I am supposed to find the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\omega)}:\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. determining $\Gamma\left(\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\omega)}:\mathbb{Q}\right)$.
My first thoughts are that any $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, so we should look at at what happens to $\alpha$ and $\omega$ under an automorphism $\sigma$. 
Thus observe by the properties of automorphisms $$\left(\sigma(\alpha)\right)^5=\sigma(\alpha^5)=\sigma(3)=3$$ thus $$\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$$
Here is where I'm stuck. From here I want to find a way to incorporate the other root, $\omega$. 

Can you start by determining the degree of the extension, i.e. the order of the Galois group?

I believe the degree is $20$ by the Tower Law.

Correct! See my answer :-)

(Big) hint. You know that $[\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta_5):\mathbf{Q}]=20$. For any $\sigma$ in the Galois group, you correctly proved that $\sigma(\sqrt[5]{3})$ is a root of $X^5-3$ and thus of the form $\zeta_5^x\sqrt[5]{3}$ for some $x\in [[0,4]]$. Also, $\sigma(\zeta_5)$ should be another primitive $5$-th root of unity.
We can prove that
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta_5)/\mathbf{Q}) &\longrightarrow \mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z} \rtimes (\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z})^\times \\
\sigma &\longmapsto (x,y),
\end{align*}$$
where $\sigma(\sqrt[5]{3})=\zeta_5^x\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\sigma(\zeta_5)=\zeta_5^y$ is a group isomorphism.
